# Why are stderr, stdin, stdout defined as macros?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99

C99 defines these three as macros that "are expressions of type ‘‘pointer to FILE’’ that point to the FILE objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams".

Given this, these expressions may or may not be `const` (i.e. the pointer may or may not be written to redirect to another file or stream); and they may have either internal or external linkage (i.e. writing to redirect to another file or stream may not persist between two separately-compiled C files).  Therefore, attempting to redirect `stdout` from within a C file may have unexpected behavior.

(Note: In gcc-9.4.0, it appears that they are macros mapped to a non-`const` variable with external linkage having the same name and accompanied by the comment: `/* C89/C99 say they're macros.  Make them happy.  */`.)

Can anyone shed some light on whether there is an official reason for this or is it safe to assume that this is another "oversight" in the original standard and that redirecting the streams should be avoided from within C code in order to keep things portable?

Comment: As the macros are defined then the pointer expressions  can not be with the qualifier const  or have internal linkage. The macros are predefined

Comment: It's important to note, that the exact nature of these macros, such as whether they are **const** or have **internal or external linkage**, is not specified by the C standard. It's implementation-dependent and can vary across different compilers and platforms.

While these macros provide convenience, it's generally recommended to use the standard I/O functions and appropriate stream redirection functions for more portable and flexible input/output operations in C code as you suggested. I'm unsure of the exact reasons, but it's probably just a historic holdover

Comment: Using `#define stdout stdout` is kosher.  The reason is most probably historical.  For a long time (197x-200x), most systems used macros like `#define stdin _ios[0]` (or possibly `&_ios[0]` — the name was in the "reserved for the system" namespace).  This meant that they could be used in file stream initializers at global scope (`static FILE *err = stderr;`).  GNU C Library changed their definition sometime in the 'oughts' and that's no longer possible.

Comment: *The macros* definitely have neither internal nor external linkage.  All macro identifiers have *no* linkage.  It is possible, however, that `stdin` *etc* are also object identifiers, and if so, *those* identifiers will have either internal or external linkage.

Comment: A C program can call `freopen` to redirect the standard streams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> these expressions may or may not be `const` (i.e. the pointer may or may not be written to redirect to another file or stream);

Correct.

> and they may have either internal or external linkage

The macro identifiers themselves have ***no*** linkage, and only if their replacement texts are identifiers is linkage even meaningful for them.

> [...] Therefore, attempting to redirect `stdout` from within a C file may have unexpected behavior.

No.  *Attempting to assign a new value to `stdout`* may fail or have unexpected results.  But yes, you have discovered that performing such an assignment is not a reliable way to change the destination to which `stdout` is connected.

> Can anyone shed some light on whether there is an official reason for this

There is an [official rationale document for C99](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf).  It does not address this point.

> or is it safe to assume that this is another "oversight" in the original standard

I don't know what you mean.  I think it's quite safe to assume that `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` were specified to be macros quite intentionally.  And it follows directly from their specifications that you cannot rely on assigning to them, for any purpose.

I infer that they are specified as they are to allow flexibility to implementations.  For example, they could be implemented as function calls or as table lookups.  They don't have to be object identifiers.

> and that redirecting the streams should be avoided from within C code in order to keep things portable?

No.  *Assigning to* `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` must be avoided for strict conformance to the C language specification (which roughly equates to "to keep things portable").  If you want to associate one of the standard streams with a different destination, then that is the primary purpose of the `freopen()` function, available in all versions of standard C.

Comment: Note that the standard says (C11 [§7.21.1.3 Files ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p6)): _The address of the `FILE` object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a `FILE` object need not serve in place of the original._ IOW: you can't simply assign or copy the `FILE` structures.

Comment: True, @JonathanLeffler, but I don't think anyone suggested doing that.  As I know you know, `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` expand to expressions of type `FILE *`, not `FILE`, and the OP's complaint is that they cannot portably assign the address of a different `FILE` to one of these.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Makes sense.  I would not that when I mentioned "internal or external linkage", I was referring to identifiers in the expression that would be expanded by the pre-compiler.   The reason I brought this up, is I have seen blogs where others assign to stdout to redirect it and I wanted to dig in a bit.  In my case, I was looking to temporarily reroute stdout for testing then route it back and wanted an easy way to do this, but I ultimately decided to wrap vfprintf inside of a function so that I can switch between streams.

Answer (score 7):

It's this way for historical reasons.

You can't reassign `stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr`.  If you need to reopen these streams so they do their i/o somewhere else, that's what `freopen` is for.

In the earliest implementations of `<stdio.h>`, there was a global array

```
FILE _iobf[20];
```

and then `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` were, yes, macros:

```
#define stdin &_iobf[0]
#define stdout &_iobf[1]
#define stderr &_iobf[2]
```

This worked fine, and it was nice and compact.  It looks "weird" to our eyes today — "Why would anyone have written it that way?", you might ask — but the point is that they *did* write it that way, and it stayed that way for many years, long enough that the C Standard had to accommodate it, by forbidding conforming programs from assigning new values to those "variables".

(To say a little more about "Why would anyone have written it that way?", I believe the answer is, economy.  When `<stdio.h>` was invented, C was brand-new, and the PDP-11 had a 64k address space, and you couldn't even always use all of it.  Everybody did raw I/O using `read()` and `write()`, or implemented their own, special-purpose buffering schemes.  Some people asked, "Why do we have to implement our own?  Why isn't there a standard one?", while others said, "Everybody's needs are sightly different; no one implementation could satisfy everyone."  It was a lot like the discussions we're still having today about why C doesn't have, say, a standard linked-list implementation.  At some point Mike Lesk declared that he *was* going to implement a standard I/O library, that it *was* possible to come up with one implementation that would satisfy everyone's needs, or well enough. But to placate the naysayers, and to not inconvenience big programs that were already bumping up against the 64k ceiling, there was a huge incentive to keep the memory footprint — both code and data — minimal.  I don't remember all the details, but that `FILE _iobf[20];` scheme really did end up being pretty darn compact, and I'm guessing that any "obviously better" scheme you might come up with — that involved, say, dynamically allocating FILE structs rather than having a fixed array of 20 of them — would have a significantly larger memory footprint.)